# Extract select elements of a list of tuples from a dataframe column

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe with column that has a list of tuples as its values like the following.

```
df1

Index  Text
-----  -----
0      [('ABC', 'NNP'), ('-', ':'), ('Jack', 'NNP'), ('Investment', 'NNP'), ('Activity', 'NN')]
```

I am trying to create a new column with a list which has the 2nd element from each tuple in the original value.

When I created a fuction and tested by passing the above text it's working as I expected.

```
def get_second_element(newlist):
  newlist2 = newlist
  mylist = [item[1] for item in newlist]
  return mylist
get_second_element([('ABC', 'NNP'), ('-', ':'), ('Jack', 'NNP'), ('Investment', 'NNP'), ('Activity', 'NN')])
```

Outcome: ['NNP', ':', 'NNP', 'NNP', 'NN']

When I applied that function to the dataframe column,

```
df1['Text'] = get_second_element(df1['Text'])

df1
Index  Text
-----  -----
0      (
```

It's only extracting the second character assuming it as long string.

Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: It seems pretty clear that you have a string not a list. If you want to manipulate it like a list of tuples, you need to turn it into a list of tuples first. One way is to `import ast` then you can: `get_second_element(df['text'].apply(ast.literal_eval)[0])`. But you should also check to see if you can get the data in the right format to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mark. I focussed on the last suggestion of yours and tried converting the data type. I also used regex to find the strings I was looking for.

```
def get_second_element(text):
  text2 = str(text)
  text3 = re.findall('\, \'(.*?)\)', text2)
  text3 = str(text3)
  return text3

df1['Text'] = df1['Text'].apply(get_second_element)
df1
Index  Text
-----  -----
0      ["NNP'", ":'", "NNP'", "NNP'", "NN'"]
```

I may need to clean it up a bit but this is what I wanted.